# Using Static "member" variables in a base class.Looking for a better approach.Singleton? or a Factory?

Tags: java, design-patterns, groovy, static-members

This may be a repetitive question and I tried looking for answers, but couldn't still get any help. So, here is the scenario:

We have test suite, with a couple of test classes and some other classes which we are using for setting up test data. We have a base class which has all its "member" variables declared as static. There is an initial set up method in that class, which loads a Map that contains literally all the config files data. Then this map is used later on to "initialize" the static "class" variables.

Then this class is "extended" for other purposes. I know by this time you all will be mad, but seriously I tried talking to the guys over here, they only laughed, and I am helpless.

Next part of the story is: the "base" class does not only provide access to some static methods, but also to these static variables (as mentioned above). Also, there is a test written where static variables get initialized always the first. In other way, all of these classes have been written in groovy. In groovy there is a method `setUpspec()` to run always the first similar to `BeforeSuite` in `TestNg`, while `setUpspec` is the method which is present in the "base" class doing all the setting of the static variables.
I am giving a snapshot of the class. I was thinking of the `Singleton` pattern, but also read about Abstract Factory, I know these design patterns except not able to make a call on which on to go for.
I would really appreciate any help in this.
Here is a snapshot:

```
class UatBaseClass extends Specification {

public static void setFieldsForTestingPurposes() {

    Properties readTestProperties;

    try {
         readTestProperties = UrlFactory.getEcnConfig("test");

        for (String key :  readTestProperties.stringPropertyNames()) {
            String value =  readTestProperties.getProperty(key);
            FINAL_CONFIG_MAP.put(key, String.valueOf(value));
        }

        env = FINAL_CONFIG_MAP.get("v3Env")
        mspEnv = FINAL_CONFIG_MAP.get("mspEnv");
        isBuildLatestFromBamboo = FINAL_CONFIG_MAP.get("getLatestBuildFromBambooYesOrNo");
        isApigeeUsed = FINAL_CONFIG_MAP.get("isApigeeYesOrNo");

        clientID = FINAL_CONFIG_MAP.get("client.id");
        clientSecret = FINAL_CONFIG_MAP.get("client.secret");

        fbIosClientId = FINAL_CONFIG_MAP.get("fb_ios_client_id");
        fbIosClientSecret = FINAL_CONFIG_MAP.get("fb_ios_client_secret");

        fbAndroidClientId = FINAL_CONFIG_MAP.get("fb_android_client_id");
        fbAndroidClientSecret = FINAL_CONFIG_MAP.get("fb_android_client_secret");

        runningIosClientId = FINAL_CONFIG_MAP.get("running_ios_client_id");
        runningIosClientSecret = FINAL_CONFIG_MAP.get("running_ios_client_secret");

        runningAndroidClientId = FINAL_CONFIG_MAP.get("running_android_client_id");
        runningAndroidClientSecret = FINAL_CONFIG_MAP.get("running_android_client_secret");

        port = FINAL_CONFIG_MAP.get("port");

        protocol = FINAL_CONFIG_MAP.get("protocol");

        url = new UrlFactory(env);

        createUserBaseUrl = url.getCreateUserUrl();
        cloudServer = FINAL_CONFIG_MAP.get("server.path")
        createUserFinalHost = protocol + "://"+cloudServer;

        //added for CoreLeaderboards
        coreCommandLeaderBoardUrl = FINAL_CONFIG_MAP.get("DEFAULT_CORE_COMMAND_BASEURL");
        coreQueryLeaderBoardUrl = FINAL_CONFIG_MAP.get("DEFAULT_CORE_QUERY_BASEURL");

        if(FINAL_CONFIG_MAP.containsKey("challenges_url")) {
            challengeElbUrl = FINAL_CONFIG_MAP.get("challenges_url")
        }else {
            challengeElbUrl = cloudServer
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        logger.error("Exception occurred while loading environment values from Jenkins,caught! exception=",e);
    }
}

public static String fetchRandomUserIdForTest() {
        String randomUpmId = null;
        if (isApigeeUsed.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
            randomUpmId =  generateRandomIds();
        }
        return randomUpmId;
}

public static String generateRandomIds() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int userId = rand.nextInt(9000000) + 1000000;
    return Integer.toString(userId);
}

public static String getCurrentTimeInMillis() {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new Date());
    logger.info("Current time:" + timeStamp);
    return timeStamp.toString();
}

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UatBaseClass.class);

public static Map<String,String> FINAL_CONFIG_MAP = new TreeMap<String, String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
protected static String clientID;
protected static String clientSecret;

protected static String cloudServer;

protected static String fbIosClientId;
protected static String fbIosClientSecret;

protected static String fbAndroidClientId;
protected static String fbAndroidClientSecret;

protected static String runningIosClientId;
protected static String runningIosClientSecret;

protected static String runningAndroidClientId;
protected static String runningAndroidClientSecret;

protected static String createUserBaseUrl;
protected static UrlFactory url;

protected static String env;

protected static String isApigeeUsed;
protected static String isBuildLatestFromBamboo;

protected static String mspEnv;

protected static String port;
protected static String protocol;
protected  static String createUserFinalHost;

protected static String coreCommandLeaderBoardUrl;
protected static String coreQueryLeaderBoardUrl;

protected static String friendsLeaderboardsRouterUrl;
protected static CreateUserDeserializedObject primaryTestUser;
protected static String primaryUserAccessToken;
protected  static String challengeElbUrl;

}
```

Comment: Code is worth 1024 words.

Comment: My bad,I missed that. Here is a snapshot.

Comment: Where is the snapshot? And can't you post is as text?

Comment: done @AndyTurner sorry,edited the text.Please let me know if you want to know more about that piece of code.

Comment: Can you post some valid code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if your problem is that the initialization method is called multiple times, I would go with the singleton pattern. Is simple to implement and does not require you to change how things work as a factory would. The first call will take longer and do the initialization, the next ones will just notice it was already done. I'm assuming that, as you said, you are already familiar with the patterns and know how to implement them.

---

EDIT: Upon seeing the new code you posted, I don't really see the need to have all those variables using extra memory, especially since they are all strings and you already have them all in your map. Just keep them on the map and use an enum for the possible keys. A single access function would suffice. Then, if you REALLY want to make a direct access, add a custom access method that fetches from the map.

Comment: yes @Daniel. Thanks for your answer.But,according to good programming practices,is it good to have those many static variables? I mean I cannot see the problem they pose,it would help if you could point me whether my assumption about not having so many static fields is correct or no. Offcourse, we have several other classes calling this class,singleton will help,but still wondering any other way to implement it.

Comment: Well, there is nothing "wrong" with static variables. The should not be avoided "just because". They are one more tool to use, with given tradeoffs. The main problem with static stuff is that is kind of outside the inheritance mechanism. Thus, no way to overload them if that is what you need.